# What is the difference between __init__ and __call__?

Tags: python, class, oop, object, callable-object

I want to know the difference between `__init__` and `__call__` methods.

For example:

```
class test:

  def __init__(self):
    self.a = 10

  def __call__(self): 
    b = 20
```

Comment: This is functionally two questions in one: "What is the `__init__` method for / what does it do?" and "What is the `__call__` method for / what does it do?" I see no reason *a priori* to suppose that they have anything to do with each other, and indeed they don't - so there isn't a meaningful way to describe a "difference between" them.

Comment: what is the difference between foo and bar

Comment: The common theme between the two is the concept of a _callable_. A Python class is a callable: `Class(arg1, ...)`. That uses the `__init__` method. An instance of a python class is also a callable: `object(arg1, ...)`. That uses the `__call__` method. Callable basically means you can write `callable(arg1,  ...)`.

Answer (score 1057, accepted):

The first is used to initialise newly created object, and receives arguments used to do that:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        # ...

x = Foo(1, 2, 3) # __init__
```

The second implements function call operator.

```
class Foo:
    def __call__(self, a, b, c):
        # ...

x = Foo()
x(1, 2, 3) # __call__
```

Comment: So, the `__init__` method is used when the *class* is called to initialize the instance, while the `__call__` method is called when the *instance* is called

Comment: That seems correct, apparently instance variables can be modified during the life of an instance which can be beneficial in some cases.

Comment: This answer implies object instantiation (via \__init__) presides over class call(via \__call__). Reference?

Comment: __init__ is called when instantiating the class:  myfoo = Foo(1,4,7.8)   __call__ is a template to call the already instantiated class to do something   let's say class Foo:\ def __call__(self, zzz)    Then, myfoo(12)  calls the class to do what that class does.

Comment: Just a note: Since functions in general are callables, they always support the method __call__. So you can call function also like this: myFun.__call__(arg)

Comment: What is practical usage of `__call__`?

Comment: The answer by Dmitriy Sintsov below raises a very important point, so I feel like I should draw attention to it here: `__call__` can return an *arbitrary value*, whereas `__init__` *must return None*.

Comment: @mrgloom, one way i have seen `__call__` used is with class-based [decorators](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/class-as-decorator-in-python/)

Comment: Does `__call__` not work when `__init__` isn't there?

Comment: We typically use the class methods to perform a specific action, e.g. String.IndexOf(). When do we call an object?

Comment: It's probably self-explanatory from the above comments, but I think also an important difference is `__init__` will run only once at instantiation although `__call__` will run each time the Object is "called".

Answer (score 345):

Defining a custom `__call__()` method allows the class's instance to be called as a function, not always modifying the instance itself.

```
In [1]: class A:
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         print "init"
   ...:         
   ...:     def __call__(self):
   ...:         print "call"
   ...:         
   ...:         

In [2]: a = A()
init

In [3]: a()
call
```

Comment: `__call__` not only allows an instance to be used as a function ... it defines the function body that's executed when an instance is used as a function.

Answer (score 116):

In Python, functions are first-class objects, this means: function references can be passed in inputs to other functions and/or methods, and executed from inside them.

*Instances of Classes* (aka Objects), can be treated as if they were functions: pass them to other methods/functions and call them. In order to achieve this, the `__call__` class function has to be specialized.

`def __call__(self, [args ...])`
    It takes as an input a variable number of arguments. Assuming `x` being an instance of the Class `X`, `x.__call__(1, 2)` is analogous to calling `x(1,2)` or **the instance itself as a function**.

In Python, `__init__()` is properly defined as Class Constructor (as well as `__del__()` is the Class Destructor). Therefore, there is a net distinction between `__init__()` and `__call__()`: the first builds an instance of Class up, the second makes such instance *callable* as a function would be without impacting the lifecycle of the object itself (i.e. `__call__` does not impact the construction/destruction lifecycle) but it can modify its internal state (as shown below).

Example.

```
class Stuff(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y, range):
        super(Stuff, self).__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.range = range

    def __call__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        print '__call__ with (%d,%d)' % (self.x, self.y)

    def __del__(self):
        del self.x
        del self.y
        del self.range

>>> s = Stuff(1, 2, 3)
>>> s.x
1
>>> s(7, 8)
__call__ with (7,8)
>>> s.x
7
```

Comment: I understand the concept, but not the special feature of *modifying its internal state*. If we in the above code replace `def __call__` simply with `def update`, we give the class an `update` method that does the same thing. It can now also modify the internal state, if called below as `s.update(7, 8)`. So, is `__call__` just syntactix sugar then?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. It's just a shortcut to invoking a method on the object without bothering to specify it. Other than that, it's like any other instance method. Interestingly, if you decorate it with @classmethod, it serves as both a classmethod and to make an instance callable. But since a classmethod can't take self, there is no state to pass around, and trying to call a class as a method calls `__init__`, so luckily it doesn't break the class construction.

Answer (score 36):

`__call__` makes the instance of a class callable. 
Why would it be required?

Technically `__init__` is called once by `__new__` when object is created, so that it can be initialized.

But there are many scenarios where you might want to redefine your object, say you are done with your object, and may find a need for a new object. With `__call__` you can redefine the same object as if it were new.

This is just one case, there can be many more.

Comment: For this specific case, should we not just create a new instance? Is this efficient in some way to modify and use the same instance.

Answer (score 36):

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self):
...         print "From init ... "
... 
>>> a = A()
From init ... 
>>> a()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: A instance has no __call__ method
>>> 
>>> class B:
...     def __init__(self):
...         print "From init ... "
...     def __call__(self):
...         print "From call ... "
... 
>>> b = B()
From init ... 
>>> b()
From call ... 
>>>
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. It answers precisely.

Answer (score 20):

`__init__` would be treated as Constructor where as `__call__` methods can be called with objects any number of times. Both `__init__` and `__call__` functions do take default arguments.

Comment: `__init__` is not a constructor function but `__new__` is. `__init__` is called right after `__new__`

Comment: I think `__new__` creates the class instance and receive a class as argument, whereas `__init__` is the instance constructor which is why it receives `self`. An easy way to see this is in the call `a = Foo(1,2,3)` the function that will receive the constructor arguments will be `__init__`.

Answer (score 18):

I will try to explain this using an example, suppose you wanted to print a fixed number of terms from fibonacci series. Remember that the first 2 terms of fibonacci series are 1s. Eg: 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13....

You want the list containing the fibonacci numbers to be initialized only once and after that it should update. Now we can use the `__call__` functionality. Read @mudit verma's answer. It's like you want the object to be callable as a function but not re-initialized every time you call it.

Eg:

```
class Recorder:
    def __init__(self):
        self._weights = []
        for i in range(0, 2):
            self._weights.append(1)
        print self._weights[-1]
        print self._weights[-2]
        print "no. above is from __init__"

    def __call__(self, t):
        self._weights = [self._weights[-1], self._weights[-1] + self._weights[-2]]
        print self._weights[-1]
        print "no. above is from __call__"

weight_recorder = Recorder()
for i in range(0, 10):
    weight_recorder(i)
```

The output is:

```
1
1
no. above is from __init__
2
no. above is from __call__
3
no. above is from __call__
5
no. above is from __call__
8
no. above is from __call__
13
no. above is from __call__
21
no. above is from __call__
34
no. above is from __call__
55
no. above is from __call__
89
no. above is from __call__
144
no. above is from __call__
```

If you observe the output `__init__` was called only one time that's when the class was instantiated for the first time, later on the object was being called without re-initializing.

Answer (score 16):

`__call__` allows to return arbitrary values, while `__init__` being an constructor returns the instance of class implicitly. As other answers properly pointed out, `__init__` is called just once, while it's possible to call `__call__` multiple times, in case the initialized instance is assigned to intermediate variable.

```
>>> class Test:
...     def __init__(self):
...         return 'Hello'
... 
>>> Test()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'str'
>>> class Test2:
...     def __call__(self):
...         return 'Hello'
... 
>>> Test2()()
'Hello'
>>> 
>>> Test2()()
'Hello'
>>>
```

Comment: This one actually explains the significance of __call__()

Answer (score 10):

So, `__init__` is called when you are creating an instance of any class and initializing the instance variable also.

Example:

```
class User:

    def __init__(self,first_n,last_n,age):
        self.first_n = first_n
        self.last_n = last_n
        self.age = age

user1 = User("Jhone","Wrick","40")
```

And `__call__` is called when you call the object like any other function.

Example:

```
class USER:
    def __call__(self,arg):
        "todo here"
         print(f"I am in __call__ with arg : {arg} ")


user1=USER()
user1("One") #calling the object user1 and that's gonna call __call__ dunder functions
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also use `__call__` method in favor of implementing [decorators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators).

This example taken from [Python 3 Patterns, Recipes and Idioms](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#python-3-patterns-recipes-and-idioms)

```
class decorator_without_arguments(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        """
        If there are no decorator arguments, the function
        to be decorated is passed to the constructor.
        """
        print("Inside __init__()")
        self.f = f

    def __call__(self, *args):
        """
        The __call__ method is not called until the
        decorated function is called.
        """
        print("Inside __call__()")
        self.f(*args)
        print("After self.f( * args)")


@decorator_without_arguments
def sayHello(a1, a2, a3, a4):
    print('sayHello arguments:', a1, a2, a3, a4)


print("After decoration")
print("Preparing to call sayHello()")
sayHello("say", "hello", "argument", "list")
print("After first sayHello() call")
sayHello("a", "different", "set of", "arguments")
print("After second sayHello() call")
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Could you please copy the output as text?

Comment: What is the point of this approach? Can you contrast it with a different approach?

Answer (score 7):

**Case 1:**

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        self.c=c
        print("init", self.a, self.b, self.c)
```

Run:

```
Example(1,2,3)(7,8,9)
```

Result:

```
- init 1 2 3
- TypeError: 'Example' object is not callable
```

**Case 2:**

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        self.c=c
        print("init", self.a, self.b, self.c)
    def __call__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.z=z
        print("call", self.x, self.y, self.z)
```

Run:

```
Example(1,2,3)(7,8,9)
```

Result:

```
- init 1 2 3
- call 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 5):

Short and sweet answers are already provided above. I wanna provide some practical implementation as compared with Java.

```
 class test(object):
        def __init__(self, a, b, c):
            self.a = a
            self.b = b
            self.c = c
        def __call__(self, a, b, c):
            self.a = a
            self.b = b
            self.c = c


    instance1 = test(1, 2, 3)
    print(instance1.a) #prints 1

    #scenario 1
    #creating new instance instance1
    #instance1 = test(13, 3, 4)
    #print(instance1.a) #prints 13


    #scenario 2
    #modifying the already created instance **instance1**
    instance1(13,3,4)
    print(instance1.a)#prints 13
```

**Note**: scenario 1 and scenario 2 seems same in terms of result output. 
But in scenario1, we again create another new instance **instance1**. In scenario2, 
we simply modify already created **instance1**. `__call__` is beneficial here as the system doesn't need to create new instance.

**Equivalent in Java**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test.TestInnerClass testInnerClass = new Test(). new TestInnerClass(1, 2, 3);
        System.out.println(testInnerClass.a);

        //creating new instance **testInnerClass**
        testInnerClass = new Test().new TestInnerClass(13, 3, 4);
        System.out.println(testInnerClass.a);

        //modifying already created instance **testInnerClass**
        testInnerClass.a = 5;
        testInnerClass.b = 14;
        testInnerClass.c = 23;

        //in python, above three lines is done by testInnerClass(5, 14, 23). For this, we must define __call__ method

    }

    class TestInnerClass /* non-static inner class */{

        private int a, b,c;

        TestInnerClass(int a, int b, int c) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Comparing to Java is completely out of the scope of the question. In your example, you don't see any difference because it was poorly selected, the numbers are the same.

Answer (score 5):

**`__init__()`** can:

- initialize the instance of class.
- be called many time.
- only return `None`.

**`__call__()`** can be freely used like an instance method.

For example, `Person` class has `__init__()` and `__call__()` as shown below:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, f_name, l_name):
        self.f_name = f_name
        self.l_name = l_name
        print('"__init__()" is called.')
        
    def __call__(self, arg):
        return arg + self.f_name + " " + self.l_name
```

Now, we create and initialize the instance of `Person` class as shown below:

```py
    # Here
obj = Person("John", "Smith")
```

Then, `__init__()` is called as shown below:

```
"__init__()" is called.
```

Next, we call `__call__()` in 2 ways as shown below:

```py
obj = Person("John", "Smith")
print(obj("Hello, ")) # Here
print(obj.__call__("Hello, ")) # Here
```

Then, `__call__()` is called as shown below:

```
"__init__()" is called.
Hello, John Smith # Here
Hello, John Smith # Here
```

And, `__init__()` can be called many times as shown below:

```py
obj = Person("John", "Smith")
print(obj.__init__("Tom", "Brown")) # Here
print(obj("Hello, "))
print(obj.__call__("Hello, "))
```

Then, `__init__()` is called and the instance of `Person` class is reinitialized and `None` is returned from `__init__()` as shown below:

```
"__init__()" is called.
"__init__()" is called. # Here
None # Here
Hello, Tom Brown
Hello, Tom Brown
```

And, if `__init__()` doesn't return `None` and we call `__init__()` as shown below:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, f_name, l_name):
        self.f_name = f_name
        self.l_name = l_name
        print('"__init__()" is called.')
        return "Hello" # Here
        
    # ...

obj = Person("John", "Smith") # Here
```

The error below occurs:

> TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'str'

And, if `__call__` is not defined in `Person` class:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, f_name, l_name):
        self.f_name = f_name
        self.l_name = l_name
        print('"__init__()" is called.')
        
    # def __call__(self, arg):
    #     return arg + self.f_name + " " + self.l_name
```

Then, we call `obj("Hello, ")` as shown below:

```py
obj = Person("John", "Smith")
obj("Hello, ") # Here
```

The error below occurs:

> TypeError: 'Person' object is not callable

Then again, we call `obj.__call__("Hello, ")` as shown below:

```py
obj = Person("John", "Smith")
obj.__call__("Hello, ") # Here
```

The error below occurs:

> AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute '__call__'

Answer (score 4):

`__init__` is a special method in Python classes, it is the constructor method for a class. It is called whenever an object of the class is constructed or we can say it initialises a new object.
Example:

```
    In [4]: class A:
   ...:     def __init__(self, a):
   ...:         print(a)
   ...:
   ...: a = A(10) # An argument is necessary
10
```

If we use A(), it will give an error 
`TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'` as it requires 1 argument `a` because of `__init__` .

........

`__call__` when implemented in the Class helps us invoke the Class instance as a function call.

Example:

```
In [6]: class B:
   ...:     def __call__(self,b):
   ...:         print(b)
   ...:
   ...: b = B() # Note we didn't pass any arguments here
   ...: b(20)   # Argument passed when the object is called
   ...:
20
```

Here if we use B(), it runs just fine because it doesn't have an `__init__` function here.

Comment: passing an object to an initialised class object. So a callable object ?

Answer (score 2):

We can use **call** method to use other class methods as static methods.

```
class _Callable:
    def __init__(self, anycallable):
        self.__call__ = anycallable

class Model:

    def get_instance(conn, table_name):

        """ do something"""

    get_instance = _Callable(get_instance)

provs_fac = Model.get_instance(connection, "users")
```

Answer (score 2):

I want to bring to the table some short cuts and syntax sugar, as well as few techniques that can be used, but I haven't see them in the current answers.

#### Instantiate the class and call it immediately

In many cases, for example when need to make a APi request, and the logic is encapsulated inside a class and what we really need is just give the data to that class and run it immediatelly as a separate entity, the instantiate class may not been needed. That is the

```
instance = MyClass() # instanciation
instance() # run the instance.__call__()
# now instance is not needed
```

Instead we can do something like that.

```
class HTTPApi:

    def __init__(self, val1, val2):
        self.val1 = val1
        self.val2 = val2

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.run(args, kwargs)

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("hello", self.val1, self.val2, args, kwargs)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create a class, and call it
    (HTTPApi("Value1", "Value2"))("world", 12, 213, 324, k1="one", k2="two")
```

---

#### Give to call another existing method

We can declare a method to the `__call__` as well, without creating an actual `__call__` method.

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, val1, val2):
        self.val1 = val1
        self.val2 = val2

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("hello", self.val1, self.val2, args, kwargs)

    __call__ = run

if __name__ == '__main__':
    (MyClass("Value1", "Value"))("world", 12, 213, 324, k1="one", k2="two")
```

This allows to declare another global function instead of a method, for whatever reason (there may be some reasons, for example you can't modify that method but you need it to be called by the class).

```
def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print("hello",self.val1, self.val2,  args, kwargs)

class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, val1, val2):
        self.val1 = val1
        self.val2 = val2

    __call__ = run

if __name__ == '__main__':
    (MyClass("Value1", "Value2"))("world", 12, 213, 324, k1="one", k2="two")
```

Answer (score 1):

**call** method is used to make objects act like functions.

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self):
...         print "From init ... "
... 
>>> a = A()
From init ... 
>>> a()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: A instance has no __call__ method

<*There is no __call__ method so it doesn't act like function and throws error.*>

>>> 
>>> class B:
...     def __init__(self):
...         print "From init ... "
...     def __call__(self):
...         print "From call it is a function ... "
... 
>>> b = B()
From init ... 
>>> b()
From call it is a function... 
>>> 

<* __call__ method made object "b" to act like function *>
```

We can also pass it to a class variable.

```
class B:
    a = A()
    def __init__(self):
       print "From init ... "
```