# __call__ or __init__ called here? Don't undestand which and why

Tags: python, class, constructor, call, init

**Edit**: this is unfortunately not answered in [What is the difference between __init__ and __call__ in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663562/what-is-the-difference-between-init-and-call-in-python)

```py
class OAuth2Bearer(requests.auth.AuthBase):

    def __init__(self, api_key, access_token):
        self._api_key = api_key
        self._access_token = access_token

    def __call__(self, r):
        r.headers['Api-Key'] = self._api_key
        r.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer {}".format(self._access_token)
        return r

#############

class AllegroAuthHandler(object):
    def apply_auth(self):
        return OAuth2Bearer(self._api_key, self.access_token)   # what will happen here?
```

I read about `__init__` and `__call__`, but I still don't undestand what is going on in this code

I don't understand:

1.) Which method will be called, `__init__` or `__call__`

2.) If `__init__`, then `__init__` doesn't return anything

3.) If `__call__`, then `__call__` can't be called with two parameters

I think `__init__` should be called, because we have `X()`, not `x()` from example below as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103903/init-or-call):

```py
x = X() # __init__ (constructor)
x() # __call__
```

Comment: Nice explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9663601/259889

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between \_\_init\_\_ and \_\_call\_\_ in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663562/what-is-the-difference-between-init-and-call-in-python)

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Unfortunately this is not explaining questions 2 and 3 :-(

Comment: @Sid Unfortunately this is not explaining questions 2 and 3 :-(

Comment: You're right that `__init__` doesn't return anything, but it's *called* on the new object, which is what gets returned when you call the class. So you could sort of imagine a `return self` and you'd have more or less the right idea.

Comment: @Blckknght Thank you! I couldn't undestand this. Now it is much clearer!

Comment: @qewghbjhb Object of type `OAuth2Bearer` will be constructed, thus __init__ will be called, then handle to this object will be returned. __call__ is not called . Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [this](https://www.google.co.il/amp/s/amir.rachum.com/amp/blog/2016/10/03/understanding-python-class-instantiation.html) is what you're looking for.

The behaviour of calling an object in Python is governed by its type's `__call__`, so this:

```
OAuth2Bearer(args)
```

Is actually this:

```
type(OAuth2Bearer).__call__(OAuth2Bearer, args)
```

What is the type of `OAuth2Bearer`, also called its "metaclass"? If not `type`, the default, then a subclass of `type` (this is strictly enforced by Python). From the link above:

> If we ignore error checking for a minute, then for regular class instantiation this is roughly equivalent to:

```
def __call__(obj_type, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = obj_type.__new__(*args, **kwargs)
    if obj is not None and issubclass(obj, obj_type):
        obj.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    return obj
```

So the result of the call is the result of `object.__new__` after passed to `object.__init__`. `object.__new__` basically just allocates space for a new object and is the only way of doing so AFAIK. To call `OAuth2Bearer.__call__`, you would have to call the instance:

```
OAuth2Bearer(init_args)(call_args)
```

Comment: Please mark this as the answer if it pleases you :)

Comment: Great answer! Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say **it's neither** here.

The part of code that's causing confusion is

```
OAuth2Bearer(self._api_key, self.access_token)
```

You need to know one thing: While `OAuth2Bearer` is the name of a class, it's also an object of class `type` (a built-in class). So when you write the above line, what's actually called is

```
type.__call__()
```

This can be easily verified if you try this code:

```
print(repr(OAuth2Bearer.__call__))
```

it will return something like this:

```
<method-wrapper '__call__' of type object at 0x12345678>
```

What `type.__call__` does and returns is well covered in other questions: It calls `OAuth2Bearer.__new__()` to create an object, and then initialize that object with `obj.__init__()`, and returns **that object**.

You can think of the content of `OAuth2Bearer(self._api_key, self.access_token)` like this (pseudo-code for illustration purposes)

```
OAuth2Bearer(self._api_key, self.access_token):
    obj = OAuth2Bearer.__new__(OAuth2Bearer, self._api_key, self.access_token)
    obj.__init__()
    return obj
```

Comment: Do I undestand correctly that  `return OAuth2Bearer(init_args)` would be `return new OAuth2Bearer(init_args)` in C# ?

Comment: @qewghbjhb I don't know C# but it appears like you're right (I read Java and they're similar so this is a guess).

Answer (score 0):

`__init__()` is called when used with Class

`__call__()` is called when used with object of Class