# When calling a class like Activation('relu')(X), how does it actually work?

Tags: python, keras

While I learn Keras, I always see a syntax like `Activation('relu')(X)`. I looked at the source code and found `Activation` is a class, so it does make no sense to me how the syntax like `Class(...)(...)` works.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/merge.py#L193) and use case of it: `A = Add()([A1, A2])`

Comment: Objects can have a `__call__` function which is called when attempting to call the object

Comment: As @BallpointBen mentioned it is `__call__` method that enables this behavior. It is a way defining objects that can act like functions. Also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9663601/2099607) answer on SO.

Comment: Thank you, everyone@BallpointBen, the __call__ does solve my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Keras, it's a bit more convoluted than vanilla Python. Let's break down what happens when you call `Activation('relu')(X)`:

1. `Activation('relu')` creates a new object of that class by calling the class `__init__` [method](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/a6afe7c8149c61372b2aae6ae331d1584eb8a19e/keras/layers/core.py#L298). This creates the object with 'relu' as parameter.
2. All objects in Python can be callable by implementing `__call__` allowing you to call it like a function. `Activation('relu')(X)` now calls that function with `X` as parameter.
3. But wait, `Activation` doesn't directly implement it, in fact it is the base class `Layer.__call__` gets called which does some checks like shape matching etc.
4. Then `Layer.__call__` actually [calls](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/cbadaf00e28f7fe42762b55f52294e3a7bb90515/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L454) `self.call(X)` which then invokes the `Activation.call` [method](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/cbadaf00e28f7fe42762b55f52294e3a7bb90515/keras/layers/core.py#L303) which applies the activation to the tensor and returns the result.

Hope that clarifies that line of code, a similar process happens when creating other layers and calling them with the functional API.

Answer (score 1):

In python, classes may have the `__call__` method, meaning that class instances are callable.

So, it's totally ok to call `Activation(...)(...)`.

The first step creates an instance of `Activation`, and the second calls that instance with some parameters.

It's exactly the same as doing:

```
activationLayer = Activation('relu')
outputTensor = activationLayer(inputTensor) #where inputTensor == X in your example
```

With this, you can also reuse the same layers with different input tensors:

```
activationLayer = Activation('relu')

out1 = activationLayer(X1)
out2 = activationLayer(X2)
```

This doesn't make a big difference with a standard activation layer, but it starts getting very interesting with certain trained layers.

Example: you want to use a standard trained VGG16 model to process two images and then join the images:

```
vgg16 = keras.applications.vgg16(......)

img1 = Input(imageShape1)
img2 = Input(imageShape2)

out1 = vgg16(img1) #a model is also a layer by inheritance
out2 = vgg16(img2)

... continue the model ....
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you expecting the `new` keyword? Python [does not use that keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html), instead uses "function notation":

> Class instantiation uses function notation. Just pretend that the class
>   object is a parameterless function that returns a new instance of the
>   class. For example (assuming the above class):
>
> ```
> x = MyClass()
> ```

Comment: There is similar syntax in `dask`. The OP isn't asking about the baseline syntax to instantiate an object, its the double `class()()` syntax. I can give a simple `dask` example: http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed.html

Comment: Hi, thank you for the lighting speed response! Guess I didn't make my question clear. Let me give another example here:https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/merge.py#L193. The usage is like: X = Add()([A1, A2]). So here we have instantiated an Add instance without any parameters by calling Add(), let's call it ADD_INSTANCE, then, what is ADD_INSTANCE([A1, A2]) doing here?

Comment: I think it was clear I was just too eager to give a response to a class syntax that confused me when I was starting general Python! Please ignore my answer, and/or downvote maybe @roganjosh should answer re:dask

Comment: Actually, the reason I'm interested in this question is because I don't really know how it works either! :)

Comment: Did @BallpointBen clarify in their comment to OP? re:`__call__`? Which was another Python feature that was foreign to me