# Member function decorator and self argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, wrapper, member-functions

The following minimal example of a decorator on a member function:

```
def wrap_function(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(args)
        print(kwargs)
    return wrapper

class Foo:
    @wrap_function
    def mem_fun(self, msg):
        pass

foo = Foo()
foo.mem_fun('hi')
```

outputs:

```
(<__main__.Foo object at 0x7fb294939898>, 'hi')
{}
```

So `self` is one of the `args`.

However when using a wrapper class:

```
class WrappedFunction:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self._func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(args)
        print(kwargs)

def wrap_function(func):
    return WrappedFunction(func)

class Foo:
    @wrap_function
    def mem_fun(self, msg):
        pass

foo = Foo()
foo.mem_fun('hi')
```

the output is:

```
('hi',)
{}
```

So the `self`, that references the `Foo` object, is not accessible in the body of `__call__` of the `WrappedFunction` object.

How can I make it accessible there?

Answer (score 2):

You're losing the reference to your *bounded* instance by wrapping the function logic (but not the instance) and redirecting it to a class instance - at that point, the class instance's own `self` applies instead of the wrapped instance method as it gets lost in the intermediary decorator (`wrap_function()`).

You either have to wrap the call to the wrapped function and pass `*args`/`**kwargs` to it, or just make a proper wrapper class instead of adding an intermediary wrapper:

```
class WrappedFunction(object):

    def __call__(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(args)
            print(kwargs)
            # NOTE: `WrappedFunction` instance is available in `self`
        return wrapper

class Foo:
    @WrappedFunction()  # wrap directly, without an intermediary
    def mem_fun(self, msg):
        pass

foo = Foo()
foo.mem_fun('hi')
# (<__main__.Foo object at 0x000001A2216CDBA8>, 'hi')
# {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, but this might be the only solution as you need it in the `__call__` function.
Would suggest checking this out: [What is the difference between __init__ and __call__ in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663562/what-is-the-difference-between-init-and-call-in-python)

```
def wrap_function(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        x = WrappedFunction(func)
        x(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```