# Access a function in a class in Python without using class.function()?

Tags: python, neural-network

I came across the following code in a neural network tutorial. The following lines works correctly although they contradict with my knowledge on Python class.

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
      super(Net, self).__init__()
      self.fc1 = nn.Linear(28 * 28, 200)
      self.fc2 = nn.Linear(200, 200)
      self.fc3 = nn.Linear(200, 10)

  def forward(self, x):
      x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
      x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
      x = self.fc3(x)
      return F.log_softmax(x)


net = Net()
net_out = net(data)
```

Here some `data` was passed into `net.forward()` and `forward()` executed.

However, to my knowledge, we have to use `net.forward(data)` instead of `net(data)` in order to access the function forward. Therefore, could anyone tell me why we can access `forward()` without mentioning the function name? Is there some sort of rule that allows us to access a function in a class without using `class_name.function_name`?

Comment: it won't happen according to my knowledge as well

Comment: Keep in mind that there's more code running than what you showed here - the base class `nn.Module` is going to have method definitions of its own, that are also accessible to instances of your class.  Apparently it defines a `.__call__()` method (that's what `net(...)` is invoking) that calls (perhaps indirectly) your `.forward()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Python` has a set of "magical" methods that you can overwrite in order to update an object's behavior. In this particular case, one way of achieving `net_out = net(data)` is overwriting the `__call__` function, which you can check out in this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663562/what-is-the-difference-between-init-and-call).

I suppose the overwriting happens in `nn.Module`. Something like the following:

```py
class Module:
    ...
    def __call__(self, arg):
        self.forward(arg)
    ...
```