# Question about classes, attributes, and methods

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, class, matplotlib, plot

I have a small question about the `.plot()` method in pandas.

So, let us say you have a dateframe saved into the variable: `df`. Let us say you wanted to make a bar chart about the data in the dataframe.

I know you can make the plot by calling `df.plot(kind='bar')`. Here, `.plot()` is a method of the `df`.

HOWEVER, you can also make the plot by calling `df.plot.bar()`. Here, `.plot` is an attribute of the `df`?

How is this possible that plot is both an attribute AND a method of the pandas `df`. I tried creating a class in python with an attribute and method having the same name, but the method overwrote the attribute. Does anyone know?

Comment: There's a `__call__`  that allows calling a class as a function. See, for example, [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/__call__-in-python/).

Comment: See [Source: panda.DataFrame.plot](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.1.0/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L607-L1702) and [Source: pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.1.0/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L1019-L1107).

Comment: THANKS Quang, i just wrote a function that did exactly what my question asked using what you said and it worked! It appears that .plot is an attribute of a pandas df, and calling it creates a plotting class which has a method .bar() OR you can simply call the class using __call__

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between \_\_init\_\_ and \_\_call\_\_?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663562/what-is-the-difference-between-init-and-call)