# understanding how PyTorch Linear works

Tags: pytorch

I am considering the sample code from the [documentation:](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html)

```
import torch
from torch import nn
#
m = nn.Linear(20, 30)
input = torch.randn(128, 20)
output = m(input)
print(output.size())
```

The output is :

```
torch.Size([128, 30])
```

The constructor of Linear is :

```
def __init__(self, in_features: int, out_features: int, bias: bool = True) -> None:
```

This is consistent with the way the instance is created, i.e.:

```
m = nn.Linear(20, 30)
```

However, when m is used, it receives **a tensor**

```
output = m(input)
```

**as input.** I do not understand why. Where is this tensor defined in the [source code?](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/linear.py)

Comment: What do you mean it "receives a tensor"? Do you mean `input` (which is created using `torch.randn`)? Or do you mean the [*model parameters*](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/linear.py#L79)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `m(input)`, the `__call__` ([what is `__call__`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663562/what-is-the-difference-between-init-and-call)) method is called, which internally calls `forward` method and does other stuff. This logic is written in the base class: [`nn.Module`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/4803eaf502fb9510a729bd1e1d3bb52744a84886/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L902). For simplicity, assume for now, that doing `m(input)` is equivalent to `m.forward(input)`.

And what's the input to `forward`? A tensor.

```
def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor
```